# Javascript: How to get the first 4 numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, extract, match

```
mystring = "9862 ....... -pack size 1 - SST Unspun Label (Roll) CAT#: 9862"
```

I want to get the first 4 numbers in this string "9862". How do I get the first sequence of numbers in this string. And store it in anothoer variable?

Javascript doesn't seem to be recognizing this variable. I don't know why.
if I do:

```
alert(mystring); //I don't get an alert pop up nor does it show any errors.
```

Could there something be wrong with the text I'm trying to store in 'mystring' variable?

Comment: yeah getting the numbers with regex from beginning mystring.match(/^[0-9]+/), are you sure that the number position does not change?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
mystring = "9862 ....... -pack size 1 - SST Unspun Label (Roll) CAT#: 9862";

mystring = mystring.substring(0, 4);

alert(mystring.trim());
```

Comment: Thanks, but if there is only 3 numbers. I'm saying 9862 is common but occasionaly I will get for example '956' a 3 digit number, substring takes the space left after the number. How do I only get the number? Like mystring.subinteger for getting numbers only and not include any spaces after as with substring method?

Comment: `mystring = mystring.trim()` will remove space around your string

Answer (score 4):

```
var extractInts = function(str) {
    r = [];
    for ( var i = 1, l = str.length; i <= l; ++i ) {
        if ( !isNaN(parseInt(str.substring(i-1, i),0))) {
            str = str.substring(i-1);
            r.push(parseInt(str, 0));
            str = str.substring( parseInt(str,0).toString().length);
            i = 1;
        }
    }
    return r;
};

var str = "Hi, here is an int 1, and another 3, and finally 37";
var i_array = extractInts(str);
console.log("extractInts: " + i_array[0]); //Prints 1
```

The above function will extract every integer into an array, and hence you can just extract the first.

Answer (score 3):

You can do either:

```
mystring=mystring.substring(from,to);
```

or

```
mystring=mystring.substr(start,length);
```

If the start is 0 (like your case), the two ways will be the same.

Sources:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is to find the first 4 digits in any string, a regex solution is also possible: `/\d{4}/` or `/[0-9]/`. See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VZt4m8/1).

A regex solution is more flexible since it allows to extract the four digits in various contexts:

```
/^\d{4}/ // To match any first 4 digits at the start of a string
/\d{4}/ // To match any first 4 digits anywhere inside a string
/word.*?(\d{4})/ // To match and capture any first 4 digits after a specific `word`
```

See a demo below:

```js
var mystring = "9862 ....... -pack size 1 - SST Unspun Label (Roll) CAT#: 9862";
console.log(mystring.match(/^\d{4}/)[0]); // The first 4 digits at the start of a string
console.log("Year: 2018".match(/\d{4}/)[0]); // The first 4 digits anywhere in a string
console.log("Year: 2012".match(/Year.*(\d{4})/)[1]); // The first 4 digits after Year
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mystring = "9862 ....... -pack size 1 - SST Unspun Label (Roll) CAT#: 9862";
var str=mystring.substr(0,4);
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to function to get first 4 char

```
mystring = "9862 ....... -pack size 1 - SST Unspun Label (Roll) CAT#: 9862"

mystring = mystring.substr(0,4);
```

or

```
mystring = mystring.substring(0,4);
```

both will work fine...try it